# What benefit is there in turning your spouse into a Vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire

I read that if you are married and am a Vampire Lord from the Dawnguard DLC you can do a quest to turn your spouse into a Vampire Lord as well.

Apart from your spouse not becoming hostile if you transform in front of them are there any other benefits to doing it, including anything that has been added by the Hearthfire DLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only benefit from the hearthfire DLC is making a coffin more accessible by placing one in the basement of your house (though this doesn't depend on having a vampire for a spouse, just if you are a vampire yourself).

Turning a spouse into a vampire does not have any explicit benefits other than what you stated.  Most of the time the only difference is that their eyes change color and that's glitchy sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as great as you would think because nothing really changes besides they're eyes. And the only other dialogue they get is when you first turn them and they say I never knew darkness held so much light. Plus they can't be cured so if you cure yourself your stuck with a vampire spouse that probably feeds on you when your sleeping. So it's not a smart decision to make. And most spouses will still go hostile if you transform into a VL anyways.